# Unexpected complex numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I'm trying to calculate a total score for a decathlon participant and there are two formulas given, one is for a field events and the other is for track events.

`Points = INT(A(B — P)^C) for track events (faster time produces a better score)`

`Points = INT(A(P — B)^C) for field events (greater distance or height produces a better score`

A, B and C are given constants for this formulas and P is the athletes performance measured in seconds (running), metres (throwing), or centimetres (jumping).

Once I am trying to calculate I get a result that is a complex number that I cannot convert into integer or smth like that.

These are the constants for A,B and C : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decathlon#Points_system

These are my values for athlete's performance (a list that I will try somehow, after adding the total score, convert into a JSON file):

`splited_info = ['Lehi Poghos', '13.04', '4.53', '7.79', '1.55', '64.72', '18.74', '24.20', '2.40', '28.20', '6.50.76']`

Could someone give me some feedback on what or how am I doing this wrong?

```
def split(info):
    with open(info.filename, "r") as f:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\n")
        for line in csv_reader:
            splited_info = line[0].split(";")
            score = 0
            score += int(25.4347 * ((18 - float(splited_info[1])) ** 1.81))
            score += int(0.14354 * ((float(splited_info[2]) - 220) ** 1.4))
            score += int(51.39 * ((float(splited_info[3]) - 1.5) ** 1.05))
            score += int(0.8465 * ((float(splited_info[4]) - 75) ** 1.42))
            score += int(1.53775 * ((82 - float(splited_info[5])) ** 1.81))
            score += int(5.74352 * ((28.5 - float(splited_info[6])) ** 1.92))
            score += int(12.91 * ((float(splited_info[7]) - 4) ** 1.1))
            score += int(0.2797 * ((float(splited_info[8]) - 100) ** 1.35))
            score += int(10.14 * ((float(splited_info[9]) - 7) ** 1.08))
            score += int(0.03768 * ((480 - float(splited_info[10])) ** 1.85))
            print(score)
```

I'm just hardcoding all the calculations since all the calculations are going to be different with all different values of A,B,C and P.

Comment: So on which athlete does it return complex numbers? By the way, `float(splited_info[10])` should immediately throw an exception because `'6.51.01'` is not a valid number.

Comment: well the first calculation goes okay, but the second one : 
score += int(0.14354 * ((float(splited_info[2]) - 220) ** 1.4)) gives me a TypeError that it cannot convert complex to int.

Ah yes, I will have to modify the last calculation , thanks for noticing :)

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko [Complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) are not “complicated”, but a specific set of numbers in maths. OP somehow gets `(4.53 - 220) ** 1.4 == (-571.1154387048516-1757.7125835285435j)`, which is weird.

Comment: @Norrius I was (wrongly) assuming that OP misused the term. `(4.53 - 220) ** 1.4` being complex makes perfect sense because `(-1)**1.4 == (-1) ** (7/5)`  is a root of unity.

Comment: I thought that maybe I am somehow didn't get the formula right, but it seems to be that this is not the thing. Cannot get why some of them work and some dont

Comment: Are you sure your data is in the correct order? (Long Jump second?)

Comment: I think 220 might be in centimetres, otherwise you're getting these negative numbers. For example, [here](http://www.ten7events.com/eng/decathlon/decathlon-points/) it is given in cm.

Comment: Well, it should be since these numbers are pretty much in the same range as in given examples in Wikipedia, and I cannot be sure, because I was just given a CSV file with 4 rows of info , that contained for example this line : 
Edan Daniele;12.61;5.00;9.22;1.50;60.39;16.43;21.60;2.60;35.81;5.25.72
So I'm just doing what was given

Comment: @Norrius I think that what I missed, maybe the constants and the given values are mixed, one in meters other in centimeters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a mix up of metres and centimetres. The Wikipedia page is slightly inaccurate in its recount of the formulae - throws are measured in **metres** but jumps should be measured in **centimetres**. This is why you're getting fractional powers of negative numbers.

See the original source for more info:

> [image]

- *IAAF Scoring Tables for Combined Events*, p. 24.